# Should I have an Allocator as a member variable in my class?

Tags: c++, allocator

If I want to make a class that uses [allocators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) (like a custom string class), should I have the `allocator` instantiated as a `member variable` or not ?

```
// Should I do this ?
template <class Allocator>
class my_class {
    Allocator a_;

    void func_that_allocates() {
        std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(a_, 10);
    }
};

// Or this ?
template <class Allocator>
class my_class {
    void func_that_allocates() {
        std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(Allocator(), 10);
    }
};

// Or maybe have a_ be a static member ?
```

My problem is that I'm trying to make a space-efficient string class that only stores the `char pointer` (to use it in a [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) along with small primitive types), but having the `allocator` as a member doubles the size of my object even with an empty `stateless allocator` (like [std::allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator)).

Comment: I recall reading all allocator instances are interchangeable. It follows from that you can pass an unnamed temporary object like your second version, if it holds true.

Comment: I think you may be refering to Allocator::is_always_equal (cf. [name requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator), at the bottom of the table), which tells you whether two instances are interchangeable for a specific Allocator type, but sadly is not a requirement for being an Allocator.

Comment: You cannot even assume that `Allocator` default-constructible, so you need to get an `Allocator` instance from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if allocator is empty, it will still contribute to the object size. In C++20 we will have [`[[no_unique_address]]` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) to address this issue (now implemented in GCC 9 and Clang 9). You'll be able to write:

```
template<class Alloc>
class S {
    int member;
    [[no_unique_address]] Alloc allocator_;
};
```

For empty class `Empty_allocator`, `sizeof(S<Empty_allocator>)` will be equal to `sizeof(int)`.

Without this attribute the standard trick is to use [empty base class optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo), deriving your class from the allocator itself. This approach is used, e.g., in libstdc++'s implementation of `std::vector`:

```
  template<typename Tp, typename Alloc>
    struct Vector_base
    {
      typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<Alloc>::template
          rebind<Tp>::other Tp_alloc_type;

      struct Vector_impl : public Tp_alloc_type
      { ... };

      const Tp_alloc_type& M_get_Tp_allocator() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return *static_cast<const Tp_alloc_type*>(&this->M_impl); }

      Alloc get_allocator() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return Alloc(M_get_Tp_allocator()); }

      Vector_impl& M_impl;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you going to use only default [standard library allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) then you don't have to hold an allocator as a field in your class.

> The std::allocator class template is the default Allocator used by all
>   standard library containers if no user-specified allocator is
>   provided. The default allocator is stateless, that is, all instances
>   of the given allocator are interchangeable, compare equal and can
>   **deallocate memory allocated by any other instance of the same
>   allocator type**.

When you are using a template - API user can specify some custom state-full allocator, in this case you will need a field.

As well as you always can use `new[]/delete[]` directly without any allocators. Or you can rewrite `func_that_allocates` in order to use stack memory only. i.e. replace: any `std::vector` with `std::array` any `std::string` with `char tmp_str[128] = {'\0'};` etc.